# VS Code-Gopls ignore specific static error check

Tags: go

I have a private module in my go.mod for which I want to use the 'latest' tag instead of versioning(v0.0.1). Problem is that gopls checks it as
require ***/module version "latest" invalid: must be of the form v1.2.3 and won't show me any other errors until I do go mod tidy. However, on Goland, it works ok.
Do you have any suggestions on how to get gopls in vs code to ignore this type of error?